# Using splash screen in XNA Game for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, splash-screen

How can i display a splash screen for my XNA game for WP7.
Can it be done by simply placing SplashScreenImage.jpg in the project(this didn't worked).
Or there is some other method.

Answer (score 2):

In your initial content load, load the splash screen image through the content pipeline. Then in your first render method call, render it to the screen. Once you've done that, you are free to load all of your other content.

This post has some great info about load times, including a link to a forum thread with some great suggestions on implementation:  http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2010/08/20/xna-and-wp7-load-times.aspx